# How to select this text field with Selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium

How do I select the credit card number field for a selenium webdriver test?

https://secure-store.nike.com/us/checkout/html/billing.jsp?_requestid=173323

```
cc = driver.find_element_by_id("creditCardNumber")
```

I get an unable to locate element error on this line and I have no idea why.

```
# click next button
driver.find_element_by_id("shippingSubmit").click()

# enter credit card number
cc = driver.find_element_by_id("creditCardNumber")
cc.click()
cc.clear()
cc.send_keys("4411111111111111")

# enter expiration
selectmonth = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("expirationMonth"))
selectmonth.select_by_value("10")

# enter expiration year
selectyear = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("expirationYear"))
selectyear.select_by_value("2012")
```

Comment: We can't get to your URL.  Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: yea I updated it, for some reason it cannot find creditCardNumber by id..

Comment: Can you paste the html for the element as well?

Comment: Since you are clicking "next" button right before that, I bet you are not waiting long enough for that element to appear and become clickable. So instead of find_element_by_id, try `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC. element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "creditCardNumber")).click()`

Comment: I got a timeout exception on that line, I don't think it can find by ID ?

Comment: you can just add to cart and click guest checkout to reach this page that I'm struggling with. http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/air-presto-ultra-flyknit-shoe/pid-10997057/pgid-11044479

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payment form is *wrapped inside an iframe element*. Switch to it before locating the element:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.switch_to.frame("billingFormFrame") 

cc = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "creditCardNumber"))
cc.click()
# ...
```

Comment: I had no idea it was inside an iframe, thanks!  However, cc.click() seems to be giving me an error.

Comment: if i change to cc = driver.find_element_by_id('creditCarNumber'),  then click works.  But how can I do what you are trying, which is to wait for element to be clickable and then click without error ?

Comment: @david okay, but what happens now if you do `cc = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "creditCardNumber"))` and then do `cc.click()`?

Comment: Hey Alec, thanks for the help. NameError "global name Select is not defined"

Comment: @david sure, add the import statement: `from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select`.

Comment: @david what is the current state of the problem, have you managed to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: Okay now it works with the import statement, thanks.